# How do I correctly choose the bounds of integration when working with a joint probability density function?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given the function $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x} \quad$  for $\quad 0 < y < x < 1$,
I'm trying to show that this is a valid probability density function. First, we can see that it is non-negative with in given interval. Secondly, I want to show that the double integral of the function within the given bounds yields 1.

My original bounds for the function were: $\int_{0}^{x}\int_{y}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dxdy$.

Doing it this way gets pretty difficult so we can change the order of integration since the function is continuous within the given bounds (right?). However I still get an incorrect answer, because my bounds were wrong. After checking the solution manual, the correct bounds are: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{x}dydx$.

This integral does indeed yeild 1, but I don't understand why when integrating with respect to x, the bounds are from 1 to 0 instead of from 1 to y, since by definition, x is bounded by 1 and y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's helpful to look at a diagram when you do the integration so you can see what you're trying to integrate. Here is a plot of the region that you are integrating over:

[image: Region 0 < y < x < 1]

If you want to integrate over this region, you can either go in the order "$dx \thinspace dy$" or "$dy \thinspace dx$". Let's go "$dx \thinspace dy$", like in your solution manual, first. As you correctly started your integral, for a specific value of $y$, $x$ is bounded between $y$ and $1$, and we are doing the integral $\int_{y}^{1} \frac{1}{x} dx$. The range of possible $y$-values is from $0$ to $1$. You are already conditioning on the fact that $x > y$ when you do the first integration, so you can consider the whole range of $y$ and do the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} \frac{1}{x} dx \thinspace dy$. The integral $\int_0^t \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x} dx \thinspace dy$ just covers the region $\{(x, y) : 0 < y < t, y < x < 1\}$.

Alternatively we could do the order "$dy \thinspace dx$". For any value of $x$ we can see from the diagram that $y$ is bounded between $0$ and $x$. And $x$ is bound between $0$ and $1$ so the integral is $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{1}{x} dy \thinspace dx = \int_0^1 x \frac{1}{x} dx = \int_0^1 1 dx = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thinking this over some more, is it true that the second bound of integration will always be the entire defined interval? The first integral can be from some number to some variable, but the second will always be two numbers?

Comment: @Jaigus Yes, that's right.

Comment: Can you please explain why that's actually the graph? after all, the given function is $\frac{1}{x}$, which is an asymptote graph, and it's the region under it we are trying to integrate, right?

Comment: Hi @HeyJude, the diagram shows the two-dimensional _domain_ of integration $\{(x, y) : 0 < y < x < 1\}$. It does not show the values of the function $f(x, y) = 1/x$ on the domain. If I could do a 3D plot I could show the whole region $\{(x, y, z) : 0 < y < x < 1, 0 < z < 1/x\}$, whose volume is calculated by the integral. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Double_integral_over_a_normal_domain